# Give an example of a monotonic increasing function which does not satisfy intermediate value property.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Give an example of a monotonic increasing function which does not satisfy intermediate value property.

> I have no idea whether that function would be continuous or discontinuous. Please give me the example(s) with proper reason. Thank you very much.

Comment: Just put in a jump at one point...take $f(x)=x-1$ for $x≤0$ and $f(x)=x+1$ for $x>0$.  Or did you want something else?

Comment: @lulu it should not satisfy IVP

Comment: @rama_ran That function does not satisfy the IVP.

Comment: My function doesn't satisfy the IVP.  For example we have $f(0)=-1$ and $f(1)=2$ so the IVP would tell us that there was a solution to $f(x)=0$ between $0$ and $1$, but there clearly isn't.  More simply, just look at the graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the intermediate value theorem says that any *continuous* $f:I \to \mathbb{R}$, where $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ is an interval (and we allow notations like $(-\infty,\infty)=\mathbb{R}$) has the intermediate value property. So in order to find a function which fails to have the intermediate value property, it had better either be

- discontinuous, or
- defined on a set which is not an interval in $\mathbb{R}$

It turns out you can get a counterexample with either strategy. The idea of the intermediate value property is that the function can't "jump" from one value to the next: it has to take every value in between.

In fact, we'll use essentially the same function for both properties. Consider the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$f(x)=\cases{0 \quad \text{ if }x<0\\1\quad \text{ if }x>0}$$
and $f(0)=0$. Then $f$ is continuous everywhere except $0$, but it does not have the intermediate value property: $f$ takes the value $0$ (at $-1$), and it takes the value $1$ (at $1$), but there is no point $x$ such that $-1<x< 1$ and $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}$, say.

If, instead of taking $f$ as a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, we choose to look at it as a function $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}$ (and do not define it at $x=0$), then it is continuous at every point at which it is defined, but fails to have the intermediate value property for the same reason. So *both* hypotheses of the theorem are necessary!

EDIT: There may be a slight confusion over whether this function is monotone increasing - this function is (according to the definition I'm used to) increasing, but not *strictly* increasing. It is pretty straightforward to use it to generate an example of a strictly increasing function, though.